# Listing purchases made from a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension where the user can make purchases using Chrome webstore.

Numerous Google pages refer to https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/check_for_payment.html . Which is dead and nowhere to be found. Great!

I am trying to find out how to get a list of **all purchases of all users** from the webstore, preferably using PHP or even by pure REST by using Postman or similar?

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link learn more about the [Payments:List](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/payments/list#request)

> Lists the [in-app products](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/payments/list#request) that the user has purchased.

If successful, the structure of the response body will be:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "chromewebstore#payment",
    "itemId": string,
    "sku": string,
    "createdTime": long,
    "state": string
  }
]
```

Parameters are also supplied in the documentation.

The state will identify if the payment is `ACTIVE`, `PAYMENT_DECLINED`, `EXPIRED`, `CANCELLED`, `REJECTED`, `PENDING`, `CANCELLED_BY_DEVELOPER`, `DISABLED`.

From there, you will now be able to filter out what data you needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only shows payments made by the current, logged in user. What if I (as product owner, regardless of user) want to list ALL purchases made by everyone. Such as the following image: https://www.simonmweber.com/images/gpc_orders_redacted.png ?